# DOM pre-populated with elements not in my HTML source

Tags: html, dom

Last night I was starting an empty project when I found out in Chrome Dev tools, that since
 my `source-code` just contains `doctype,html,head and body` tags, my DOM is somehow 
pre-populated with some weird elements.

[image]

My source code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

I have tried clearing cache but it stays this way. `Firefox` and `Safari` look OK.
 Can someone please explain what is happening? Is this a Chrome thing? I haven't noticed it before..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the [Orbvious Interest](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/orbvious-interest/bkikpncfbjndhfkipijhdoddiadaipaa?hl=en) extension installed in Chrome. Extensions can add DOM elements.

Comment: Wow, you are right! I had no idea that Chrome extensions are allowed to add code to the DOM. I thought that it was all happening in some sort of a sandbox mode. Thanks!